# Why do I get no output in my python multiply function using lambda?

Tags: python, function, lambda

I need to make a function that takes 'a' and 'b' fomr user and then multiplies them using lambda and returns result, but it isn't working for me

```
def multiply(a,b):
    x = lambda a, b: float(a * b)
    return x

a = input()
b = input()
a = float(a)
b = float(b)
print(multiply(a,b))
```

Comment: You create the lambda but never call it: `return x(a, b)`

Comment: Try using `x = (lambda a, b: float(a * b))(a, b)` to call the defined `lambda` function. You should probably just `return a * b` in the `multiply()` function and leave the `lambda` line out.

Comment: Maybe you want to make `multiply` a lambda and not a function: `multiply = lambda a, b: float(a * b)`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
def multiply(b):
   return lambda a: a * b
a = input()
b = input()
a = float(a)
b = float(b)
c = multiply(b)
print(c(a))
```